Is there a way to *not* request userinfo.email and userinfo.profile scopes for Google Marketplace apps?
Under https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket-component.googleapis.com/googleapps_sdk?project=myproject
I'd like to only have drive.file, but whenever I save, it keeps re-adding userinfo.email and userinfo.profile. How do I make it stop doing that? I don't want access to any userinfo.

